# Arduino Serial monitor writes data twice

Tags: c, arduino, avr

I have a sketch written in Arduino IDE which monitors on 2 RXs pins signal data and writes it to Serial Monitor. I have a problem that it from 1 RX the data are always written twice, but another RX (response) is OK, what could be the problem?

So I don't think it is problem in program of MCU.

Comment: What's connected?  What's sending?  What's being sent?   Which one double prints and which one is OK?  Man, you've given almost no information to go on here.  What do you expect anyone to be able to do?

Comment: Are you maybe doing local echo and remote echo?

Comment: I attached image of communication. 
I have a board with MCU(AVR) and GSM module SIM800L, I connected this arduino to Rx and Tx of MCU so I can see the whole communication. Commands from MCU (AT Commands) are doubled in Arduino Serial Monitor and response from GSM is printed normally. In MCU I use for sending simple functions (I will edit my topic and put it there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SIM800L module may have Command Echo enabled. You can send the following commands to change it:

```
ATE0        // Disable echo temporarily; After SIM800 reset, saved setting will be used.
ATE1        // Enable echo temporarily; After SIM800 reset, saved value will be used.

ATE0&W      // Disable echo and save setting
ATE1&W      // Enable echo and save setting
```

Reference: [SIM800_Series_AT_Command_Manual](https://www.elecrow.com/wiki/images/2/20/SIM800_Series_AT_Command_Manual_V1.09.pdf) (page 35, page 355 end)

Comment: It helped! Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad that it helped. And welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)